# R : str_replace_all function not converting "2010-12-31+10" to "2011-01-10"

Tags: r, dataframe, stringr

I have a string like this:

```
str1 <- "get all securities in portfolio port1 on date 2010-12-31 where field value of Close on 2010-12-31+10 less than 2000"
```

I am trying to convert "2010-12-31+10" to "2011-01-10" in `str1`.
I tried `str_replace_all` method of `stringr` package
But i didnt get the output.

```
> str_replace_all(str1,"2010-12-31+10","2011-01-10")
[1] "get all securities in portfolio port1 on date 2010-12-31 where field value of Close on 2010-12-31+10 less than 2000"
```

What is the reason for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument of `str_replace_all` is not a character string but a regular expression. So you have to escape the symbols such as `+` that have a special meaning in regexps :

```
R> str_replace_all(str1,"2010-12-31\\+10","2011-01-10")
[1] "get all securities in portfolio port1 on date 2010-12-31 where field value of Close on 2011-01-10 less than 2000"
```

Or you can use the `fixed` function of `stringr` to make it match your pattern as a regular string :

```
R> str_replace_all(str1,fixed("2010-12-31+10"),"2011-01-10")
[1] "get all securities in portfolio port1 on date 2010-12-31 where field value of Close on 2011-01-10 less than 2000"
```